# message box in PHP and navigation to another page

Tags: javascript, php

I am creating a login page in PHP. On entering wrong username/password I am showing a javascript alert box. I now want to navigate user back to login page on clicking "OK" button of alert box . Am using "header(location:url)", but then javascript code is not working. 
Is there any other way to do this.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to show the incorrect log in notification in alert box?

Comment: I dont want to show incorrect log, just I want user to go back to login page with message saying wrong username/password displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('error');  
      </script>";
 echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1; URL=login.php'>";
```

Comment: And one more question, I am using javascript to check whether username and password are not empty. If one of these is empty, PHP script should not work, that is username and password validation should not occur. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For JS redirect, try;

```
window.location.href="http://url";
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in the login error page ..

```
<script>
 alert('Wrong Username/Password');
 window.location = "http://www.google.com";
</script>
```

But if you are familiar with jquery i advice you to do the login process with ajax request and show the notifications in the same page instead of navigating back and forth.

If you need i can create a simple one in plnkr

Answer (score 0):

For the js redirect, u can use

`window.location.href='http://whereEver';`

Note: Username/ password validations are server side. Assuming its an ajax call, after you get the validation results, instead of triggering an alert, have a div in the page itself where you can inject the server response. Alerting looks unprofessional.

Better approach would be something like

**HTML**

`<div class="response"></div>`

**CSS**

```
.response {
    display:none;
}

.error {
   color: red; // find a better color
}
```

**PHP**

On validation failure, have a variable, lets call it `status` and make it false.
The validation response can be something like,

`$response = ['status' => false, 'message' => 'Username / password mismatch'];`

Then send back the results

`die(json_encode($response));`

Note: If you are using PHP < 5.4, use

`$response = array('status' => false, 'message' => 'Username / password mismatch');`

**JS**

`$.ajax({
    url: 'url-to-post',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('form[name="your-form-name"]').serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        if (!data.status) {
            // inject into response
            $('.response').addClass('error').html(data.message).show();
        }
        else
        {
            // redirect them to home page, i assume
            window.location.href = '/home';
        }
    }
});`